# High Logical Reads

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete, query-performance

I'm running SELECT and DELETE operations on same table but in both operations, logical reads are way different and in result of this query is taking much higher time while deleting data. Can you please help me to reduce logical reads in delete operation.

Table is having more than 190 millions of rows and it is to keep 90 days of data from yesterday backwards.

I encountered with this problem while making SP which will be deleting data of 1 days (most oldest data) on daily basis

I've checked and done with necessary INDEXES and I have also tried with disabling indexes but still time is much higher.

SELECT Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [db_name].dbo.[table_name] ldt
WHERE ldt.[DATE]='2019-03-26'
```

DELETE Query:

```
DELETE FROM [db_name].dbo.[table_name]
WHERE [DATE]='2019-03-27'
```

Logical-Reads for SELECT operations are: 60,383 and query processing time is 00:00:32.851
Logical-reads for DELETE operations are: 64,516,671 and query processing time is 00:10:27.902 (expected time is less than a minute)

Comment: off-topic for SO - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). And no one can help without knowing the DDL of the table and without seeing the execution plan. If the table has triggers or indexed views, then include those.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at table partition with file groping? if you can create partition on your data, you could truncate an specific partition instead of deleting it.

Comment: partitioning would not be suitable for me because I have to keep 90 days days on running window in aforementioned table. Further to that, would it be helpful to disable Non-clustered indexes before performing delete operation and than rebuild them?